# "An illegal choice has been detected"

Tags: 7, forms

I have an image field attached to a content type created. When I upload images to it, it gives me an error "an illegal choice has been detected please contact sight administrator."  I get this error when uploading images only on this content type.

[image: screenshot]

I cleared watchdog entries, form and image cache tables; it started working again, but when I create a second page, the problem shows again.

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://drupal.org/node/1212868#comment-578468).

The required field radio button was not selected, when the image was uploaded. It seems an error with the form validating when the image is uploaded.